# Is there a reason the java compiler cannot just substitute .equals for == when comparing objects?

Tags: java

In java we need to compare objects using `.equals()` instead of `==`. But why can't the compiler do this for us? For example:

```
if (myString == myOtherString){
    doSomething();
}
```

why cant the compiler go "oh, we're comparing objects!", and change it to this:

```
if (myString.equals(myOtherString))
```

Why do we do this manually?

Edit - Guys, I know the difference between == and .equals(). You can stop telling me how ignorant I am. My question was why not just substitute .equals() since its what you want 99% of the time. I have learned that there are cases where knowing if two objects are truly the same reference is useful.

Comment: Because some times you do want to use `==`.

Comment: sometimes you want to know if you really got the same object, and not just something that looks the same.

Comment: Can you give an example where that would be useful?

Comment: `My question was why not just substitute .equals() since its what you want 99% of the time` Your question makes no sense. You're essentially suggesting that testing for referential equality should be removed which is a horrible idea. To give you an example, there may be several `Person` objects that refer to the same location (because it's the same person) but just exist in different collections. You can use `==` to test this reference.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator and `equals()` often do quite different things. It's only the *default* implementation of `equals()` inherited from `Object` that reverts to using `==`. (`String` is a good example: strings that are `equal()` are often not `==`.) Also, the first example in your code will execute fine if `myString` is `null`, while the second will throw an exception.

Sometimes you really just want to know if two object references are to the same object, not whether they refer to objects that have "the same contents" (the meaning of which is usually what `equals()` implements). Automatically converting `==` to `equals()` would be a bad idea.

Comment: Dear Ted Hopp, plz help me at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495499/admob-interstitial-matched-requests-is-too-low-10/33510532#33510532

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason the java compiler cannot just substitute .equals for == when comparing objects?

Java uses both `equals()` and `==`

When you use `==` to compare objects, you are comparing whether the 2 objects reference the same instance.

When you use `.equals()`, most of the time you will be comparing one or some of the attributes of the 2 objects. (Comparing the 2 objects' content)

**Example for use of == in optimization**

```
public boolean equals(square s){
    if(this == s){    //If s and this object is the same instance 
        return true;  //return true straight away, no further checking needed
    }
    return (this.length == s.getLength() && this.breadth == s.getBreadth());
}
```

Comment: `==` tests identity, `equals` tests state

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference. `equals(Object)` checks if two objects are **equal** - i.e., have the same state. The `==` operator checks if two references indeed point **to the same object**. It isn't a common usecase, but it definitely has its usages - e.g., to borrow from [`IdentityHashMap`'s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html):

> A typical use of this class is topology-preserving object graph transformations, such as serialization or deep-copying. To perform such a transformation, a program must maintain a "node table" that keeps track of all the object references that have already been processed. The node table must not equate distinct objects even if they happen to be equal. Another typical use of this class is to maintain proxy objects. For example, a debugging facility might wish to maintain a proxy object for each object in the program being debugged.