# Admob Interstitial matched requests is too low (~10%)

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

Last 15 days until now, My admob interstitial unit id always get too low of matched requests.
With 15000 Interstitial requests, i just got ~1500 matched (~10%).

I can't find what is the root cause. Whether low matched is  coming from admob server side or client side (it's mean i implement as wrong way).

Someone can help me, and this is some the code that i have implemented:

Firstly, i create interstitial.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     initUI();
    // setup  interstitial admob
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(interstitial_ad_unit_id);

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            Log.d("AdListener", "onAdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            Log.d("AdListener", "onAdFailedToLoad");
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
            Log.d("AdListener", "onAdOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            Log.d("AdListener", "onAdClosed");
            interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();
            Log.d("AdListener", "onAdLeftApplication");
        }

    });

    interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

And then, whenever i need to show Ads, i call this method:

```
    public static void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();

    } else {
        // show another ads network instead of admob, such as StartApp
        displayInterstitialStartApp();

        // if interstitial is not loading then load again
        if (!interstitial.isLoading()) {
            interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you guys think about this method: onAdFailedToLoad(). In my opinion, when it load fail then i load it again, but Admob has no ads response at this time. Then it load failed again -> then load ... So, i think this is the big problem. It go to infinity loop, too many request but have no matched.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use mediation so that if Admob cannot serve an ad it falls back to other ad networks. Admob provides this out of the box, just configure the other ad networks on the Admob web page.

Comment: What do you think about this method: onAdFailedToLoad(). In my opinion, when it load fail then i load it again, but Admob has no ads response at this time. Then it load failed again -> then load ... So, i think this is the big problem. It go to infinity loop, too many request but have no matched.

Comment: Correct. That is why having 3-4 ad networks in your mediation list works best. If the first doesn't return something the mediator asks the 2nd and so on. You don't need to manage it yourself.